# Variable length nested for loops with different function calls at each level

Tags: python, loops, nested

Although some variants of this question has been asked, I could not find what I was looking for.

Let us say I have a variable length vector of instances of different classes: [objA, objB, objC], each of which have a method called `call_method()` that returns a particular value `v`, and a boolean `s`, the call_method() are infact like "generators" that return a new `v` and a new `s` for every call. They are actually wrappers around generators, that set `s` as True if the generator returned an object, else false

I would like to have a structure like:

```
while True:
  v1, s1 = objA.call_method()
  if s1 == False:
    break # It is a failure
  while True:
    v2, s2 = objB.call_method()
    if s2 == False:
      break # break out of the middle loop and call objA again for a new v1, s1
    while True:
      v3, s3 = objC.call_method()
      if s3 == True:
        return [v1, v2, v3]
      if s3 == False:
        break #i.e. call objB again.
```

As you can see here, I do not need a `while True` for the third object, since I will exit the loop whether true or false. (Just added it here for completeness). Only if the outerloop succeeds (i.e. s = True), it enters the inner loop, and it goes on.

What would the best way be to implement this for an arbitrary list of [objK]?

Comment: Do you need to preserve v1, s1, v2, s2 etc?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by that? I do not need `s1` as you can see it is just a check for entering the next for loop, but I finally need to return `v1, v2, v3` if `s3` is set to true

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that return statement.  I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of objects with the `call_method` method, you can call the method of the object at an index that matches the size of a separate output list you use to store the returning values of calls to `call_method`. Discard the last value in the output list if the returning flag is `False`. If there is no value in the output list to discard, it means you have a failure, in which case it is best to raise an exception. You have a success when the size of the output list matches the size of the input list:

```
def call_method_until_all_success(objs):
    values = []
    while (index := len(values)) < len(objs):
        value, success = objs[index].call_method()
        if success:
            values.append(value)
        elif values:
            values.pop()
        else:
            raise RuntimeError # it is a failure
    return values

print(call_method_until_all_success([objA, objB, objC]))
```